# How to populate array with a div ID by the divs class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Lets say I have 4 divs that share the same class and unique ID's like the following;

```
<div id="Komori1" class="press">
<div id="Komori2" class="press">
<div id="PressD" class="press">
<div id="PressE" class="press">
```

And I create an array in the script like the following;

```
var pressArray =[]
```

Now I want to populate this array with the Id names of all instances of class name "press" in the html body, how I can do this is?

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Comment: The question has a `jquery` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `map()` and `get()` methods to get array of `id`'s

```js
var pressArray = $('.press').map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();

console.log(pressArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Komori1" class="press">
<div id="Komori2" class="press">
<div id="PressD" class="press">
<div id="PressE" class="press">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how without jQuery:

```js
pressArray = [];
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.press')).forEach(function(el) {
  pressArray.push(el.id)
});
document.write(pressArray);
```

```html
<div id="Komori1" class="press"></div>
<div id="Komori2" class="press"></div>
<div id="PressD" class="press"></div>
<div id="PressE" class="press"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Easy, grab all `.press` elements and then map their id values to the array.

**Non-jQuery:**

```js
var pressEls = document.querySelectorAll('.press');
var pressArray = [].map.call(pressEls, function(el) {
  return el.id;
});

alert(pressArray);
```

```html
<div id="Komori1" class="press">
<div id="Komori2" class="press">
<div id="PressD" class="press">
<div id="PressE" class="press">
```

**jQuery:**

```js
var $pressEls = $('.press');
var pressArray = $pressEls.map(function() {
  return this.id;
}).get();

alert(pressArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Komori1" class="press">
<div id="Komori2" class="press">
<div id="PressD" class="press">
<div id="PressE" class="press">
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var pressArray =[];

$(".press").each(function() {
  pressArray.push($(this).attr('id'));
});

$(".result").html(pressArray.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Komori1" class="press">
<div id="Komori2" class="press">
<div id="PressD" class="press">
<div id="PressE" class="press">

  
<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through each element with `press` class and push its id to the pressArray variable.

```js
var pressArray = [];
$(".press").each(function(i) {
  pressArray.push(this.id);
});
alert(pressArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Komori1" class="press">
<div id="Komori2" class="press">
<div id="PressD" class="press">
<div id="PressE" class="press">
```

With just plain JavaScript you can use a for loop to loop through the elements with the class `press`.

```js
var pressArray = [];
for(var i=0, n=document.getElementsByClassName("press"); i<n.length; i++) {
  pressArray.push(n[i].id);
};
alert(pressArray);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Komori1" class="press">
<div id="Komori2" class="press">
<div id="PressD" class="press">
<div id="PressE" class="press">
```